# Installing AIDE in Alpine

Tags: alpine, aide

I'm trying to make my Alpine instance more secure by installing AIDE but it doesn't seem to be in the repos:

```
#apk add aide
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  aide (missing):
    required by: world[aide]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add aide' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is there a way to install it in Alpine?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no package for AIDE available in the [Alpine repositories](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=aide&branch=edge).

IMHO AIDE is not a good fit to run inside a Docker container.